# How to save SSMS 2012 Object Explorer Scripting Settings?

Tags: ssms, configuration, scripting, default-value

I'm generating a bunch of object creation scripts in SSMS 2012, using the Object Explorer context menu.  The default options for these generated scripts are not to my liking (for example, I want the permissions and the triggers scripted).  I went into Tools|Options|SQL Server Object Explorer|Scripting and set the scripting options how I wanted them, and that worked great for that day, but now it's another day and I've come back to continue working on this, and all of my customized scripting settings have been lost.

I went into the Import and Export Settings Wizard, hoping to export my changes and then just import them all at once next time.  But I don't see these settings anywhere in the wizard.  So what's up?  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,

Rebeccah

Comment: I suggest you update to new version of SSMS. I just changed bunch of setting (same as yours), closed SSMS, reopened and the settings are there. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms